Speed-up reading/writing operations from PCIe bus and disk using C++ on Windows
I'm developing a C++ application with GUI (Qt) for reading data from PCIe bus and writing them as binary output file on an NVMe drive. This is my actual code
void SCCCUtilityTool::on_streaming_read_button_clicked() {

    qDebug() << "[on_streaming_read_button_clicked] READ button clicked";

    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(start_read_thread);
}

void start_read_thread() {

    auto read_data = std::make_unique<std::vector<uint32_t>>(dma_array_elements, 0);

    try {
        const auto device_paths = get_device_paths(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_XDMA);
        if (device_paths.empty()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to find XDMA device!");
        }

        xdma_device dev(device_paths[0]);

        qDebug() << "[start_read_thread] read_data.size() -->" << read_data->size();

        std::thread read_thread(read, std::ref(dev),
            (void*)read_data->data(), read_data->size() * sizeof(uint32_t), dma_block_size_bytes);

        read_thread.join();

    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}

void read(xdma_device& dev, void* buffer, const size_t size, const size_t block_size) {

    size_t bytes_remaining = size;
    qDebug() << "[read] bytes_remaining --> " << bytes_remaining;

    // Open the file in binary append mode
    std::ofstream outfile("D:\\output.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    if (!outfile.is_open()) {
        qDebug() << "[read] Failed to open the output file.";
        return;
    }

    // Start timing
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    try {
        while (bytes_remaining > 0) {

            const size_t offset = size - bytes_remaining;
            const size_t bytes_to_read = bytes_remaining < block_size ? bytes_remaining : block_size;
            
            const size_t bytes_read = dev.read_from_engine((char*)buffer + offset, bytes_to_read);
           
            bytes_remaining -= bytes_read;

            // Write the read data to the file
            outfile.write((char*)buffer + offset, bytes_read);
            if (!outfile) {
                qDebug() << "[read] Failed to write to the output file.";
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to write to the output file.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

    // End timing
    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end_time - start_time;
    double throughput = size / duration.count() / 1048576;

    outfile.close();

    qDebug() << "[read] Finished reading " << size - bytes_remaining << "bytes";
    qDebug() << "[read] Throughput: " << throughput << " MB/s";
}

size_t xdma_device::read_from_engine(void* buffer, size_t size) {
    
    unsigned long num_bytes_read;
    if (!ReadFile(c2h0.h, buffer, (DWORD)size, &num_bytes_read, NULL)) {
        qDebug() << "[read_from_engine] Read error";
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read from stream! " + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
    }
    return num_bytes_read;
}

Everything goes well, I can read from PCIe the data that the FPGA hardware sends to me and I can write them to my outfile file.
Problems come with performance; as you can see in the code I tried to evaluate the global throughput from the opening and the closing of the file and it's quite low at the moment.
Leaving aside any hardware upgrades that will come that do not affect me, on the software side, what changes can I make to improve performance?

Have a pool of 8 KB buffers and read to them each time, then push them on a queue for a worker thread to write them to disk then push them back into the pool.

auto read_data = std::make_unique<std::vector<uint32_t>>(dma_array_elements, 0); Why do you ever need am owning pointer to a vector?! The vector is an owning pointer to its data by itself. And why do you need a buffer larger than block_size if you only ever read block_size at a time? Read it, write it, forget it. No need to keep track of the offset or anything. Once you wrote it, the buffer is as good as an empty one.
